# Does google charge for data transfered into Google Cloud Storage

Tags: backup, google-cloud-storage

Currently we are using Amazon AWS S3 as a backup solution for our servers. Amazon AWS clearly states: "All data transfer in - $0.000 per GB". With Google Cloud Storage I can not find a clear answer.

From what I can find the egress and interconnect data transfer is defined. Interconnect is of course not relevant here. Egress means for as far as my english and the dictionary goes meaning outgoing transfer.

So how is the incoming data measured or are only the number of POST / PUT operation's calculated?

Hope that anyone who has been using Google for a while can elaborate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ingress cost is 0 for any amount of data, as mentioned in network pricing on [this page](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#network-pricing). The PUT/POST operations though are charged at $0.10 per 10,000 operations as per [this page](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#operations-pricing). In short for ingress, data is free, operations are not.

Comment: I can't believed I missed that, thank you very much for clarifying!